# What's the best GUI designer for use with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

This question was asked a couple years ago and the answers give out-dated recommendations, so here it is again. What is the best GUI designer for use with Eclipse?

Comment: Please define "best".  Fastest?  Cheapest?  Full-employment for junior programmers?  What do you think is "best"?

Comment: @S.Lott In the interest of being generic, shall we assume "any of the above"?

Comment: I prefer to just do it myself.  Choose the LayoutManager that will work best, place the components where I want them, set the sizes that I want, and call `pack()`.

Comment: @jrharshath: "In the interest of being generic" I claim "best" means "most expensive" and "most restrictive licensing agreements" and "most compatible with NetBeans".  What do generic definition of "best" would you like to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the next "Visual Editor" is still in the making, [with e4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4):
See [Getting started with e4 Application using Visual Designer](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/yvesyang/2010/02/19/getting-started-of-e4-application-using-visual-designer/) (also in the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/E4Designer))

[image]

Combined with the **[XWT designer](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/yvesyang/2009/11/02/xwt-designer/)**, you get a WYSIWYG editor for XWT, a tool like VE of eclipse, but with a completely different architecture.
XWT Designer relies on XML, instead of Java in VE. And also it doesn’t have two JVMs as VE

[image]

The [XWT being a declarative approach](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT/Running_the_demos) to GUI, an full fledge Visual Editor won't be needed at all time. A simple text editor can be enough at first.

Answer (score 0):

For android projects, the built in layout editor.

*I'm also marking this community, since there is no real answer*